# Can I use putty to create a tunnel through which the packages will be updated?

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, windows, putty

the task is as follows:

1. There are several servers on centos without internet access.
2. There is a Windows PC with Internet access and to all servers with CentOS.
3. CentOS servers do not have access to a Windows PC.
4. Connecting to Centos using Putty.

Is it possible to create a tunnel using Putty without installing additional software on CentOS, so that CentOS servers can update/install packages?

Comment: Point 3 and 4 are confusing. If you can connect to CentOS using Putty, it means Windows-PC has access to CentOS servers.

Comment: Yes, the network is configured so that I can connect to CentOS with Windows, but there is no reverse connection from CentOS to Windows. At the moment, I have a working scheme only with additional software. On Windows, there is an Http proxy, and in the Putty settings, there is the creation of a tunnel to the proxy port installed in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Windows-PC to forward traffic to internet on behalf of CentOS servers. This is a bad idea though because you are breaching company security policies.

From a Windows-PC (Windows 10), open CMD or PowerShell, and execute the following two commands. The two commands will create a reverse SOCKS proxy.

```
ssh -R 8888:localhost:9999 remotehost &
ssh -D 9999 localhost
```

From a CentOS machine, configure proxy to point to `localhost:8888` (either system-wide or under yum config).
For more reading, check the ssh manpages, under the `-R` option